# Find Count of Timespan overlap in Daterange

Tags: c#, .net

Let's say we have a Date range like: **2019-05-26 07:12:00** to **2019-11-26 19:15:00**

And we got Two timespans: **07:00** and **08:00**  for calculation of breakfast.

Now I had to calculate how many time this time overlap occurred.

this is what I wrote so far but I know I miss some times in start & end of periods:

```
var breakfast = 0;
for (DateTime date = StartDate; date.Date <= EndDate; date = date.AddDays(1))
{

    if (date.TimeOfDay >= new TimeSpan(0, 07, 00, 00) && date.TimeOfDay <= new TimeSpan(0, 08, 00, 00))
    {
        breakfast++;
    }
}

///////
var lunch = 0;
for (DateTime date = StartDate; date.Date <= EndDate; date = date.AddDays(1))
{
    if (date.TimeOfDay >= new TimeSpan(0, 13, 00, 00) && date.TimeOfDay <= new TimeSpan(0, 14, 00, 00))
    {
        lunch++;
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What are you going to calculate? Time overlaps or how many items people had breakfast?

Comment: How many time people have breakfast

Comment: So all you really need to do is check if the first and last datetimes overlap the breakfast/lunch times, and then multiply the number of days inbetween by 2 (one breakfast per day, one lunch per day)?

Comment: Based on timesan I had to calculate for example breakfast=4 lunch=4 dinner=3

Comment: OK, but my point was that you don't need to check every single one of the days that they have some time that overlaps those period since all except the first and last days are 24 hours long, right?

Comment: Yes, but maybe we have only one day length period.

Comment: I was simply offering some advice. I wasn't trying to solve your entire problem, hence it being a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Now, you say that you have a date range. `StartDate` and `EndDate`. Let's say they have values as follows:

```
StartDate = new DateTime(2019,05,26,07,12);    // "2019-05-26 07:12"
EndDate = new DateTime(2019,11,26,19,15);    // "2019-11-26 19:15"
```

Now when you write:

```
for (DateTime date = StartDate; date.Date <= EndDate; date = date.AddDays(1))
```

each time this loop runs, you will get `date.TimeOfDay` as 07:12 for each iteration. This means that if the time component of `StartDate` does not fall between 07:00 and 08:00 range, then it is not going to fall for any other day in the loop as well.

Therefore, we can simplify the whole counting process in the following way:

```
var breakfast = 0;
if (StartDate.TimeOfDay >= new TimeSpan(0, 07, 00, 00) && StartDate.TimeOfDay <= new TimeSpan(0, 08, 00, 00))
{
    breakfast++;
    breakfast += EndDate.Date.Subtract(StartDate.Date.AddDays(1)).Days;
    if(EndDate.TimeOfDay >= new TimeSpan(0, 07, 00, 00))
        breakfast++;
}
```